# The probability that the number of heads among $100$ flips of a fair coin is divisible by $3$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Its very late and I think I must be a bit crazy in the head. I remembered the following classic question: if you flip a fair coin, say 100 times, what is the probability that the number of heads is divisible by 3? I know how to solve this with generating functions + roots of unity filter, and I get the correct answer. However I have an alternate reasoning which produces a different answer: given the first $97$ flips, the number of heads among the last $3$ flips is determined (by considering modulo $3$), thus the probability is $1/27$.

What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Calm down and think. That kind of attitude will not get things right. :)

Comment: I'm half asleep. But I realize my mistake now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have flipped 97 times.  One of three situations will have occurred, either you flipped 0mod3 heads, 1mod3 heads, or 2mod3 heads.

If you flipped 0mod3 heads, the only way to continue to be a multiple of 3 is by either flipping three heads, or three tails (2/8 probability)

If you flipped 1mod3 heads, the only way to become a multiple of 3 is by flipping two heads out of the three flips (3/8 probability)

If you flipped 2mod3 heads, the only way to become a multiple of 3 is by flipping one head out of the three flips (3/8 probability).

Notice that the probability that you flip a multiple of 3 number of heads in 100 flips is **dependent** on the outcomes of the first 97 flips, hence you must use a different approach to successfully answer.